# angular form unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-forms

```
    public isValidStartDate() {
      return this.form.controls.dueDate.touched && this.form.controls.dueDate.errors &&
          !this.form.controls.dueDate.hasError('required')
    }
    public invalidDueDate() {
      return this.form.controls.dueDate.touched && this.form.controls.dueDate.hasError('required');
    }


  it('should check a valid data', () => {
    const dueDate = component.form.controls['dueDate'];
    expect(component.isValidStartDate()).toBeFalsy();
    expect(component.invalidDueDate()).toBeFalsy();

// Not working toBeTruthy
expect(component.isValidStartDate()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(component.invalidDueDate()).toBeTruthy();

  });
```

I need help for write unit test for toBeTruthy, any one can help please thanks

I don't know how to write test case for toBeTruthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First condition in `isValidStartDate` says `this.form.controls.dueDate.touched`, so to imitate `touched` state you could call `dueDate.markAsTouched()` (https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsTouched)